# Checking if CRM record exists

Tags: c#, sharepoint, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have CRM URL's and I want to check if CRM records exist using those URL's. The easiest and fastest way would be to check the page for the value "Record is unavailable" to my knowledge.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(crmLink);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
bool websiteExists = (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
string siteContents = "";
if (websiteExists)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        siteContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Two problems, almost the whole body is an iframe, second problem is when I check the value of "siteContents" I do not see an iframe. My whole idea about how to get the CRM record may be wrong; CRM isn't exactly my field of expertise.

[image]

Comment: is that the long version of the url or the short one with # ?

Comment: @Lidaranis The long version e.g. http://SITENAME.com/CRMDev/main.aspx?etn=account&pagetype=entityrecord&id=36345eb0-728c-e611-9421-00153d29152e#195805481

Comment: Ok, that looks about right. But there is one thing I need to know. do you have access to the organization service? can you use the crm sdk?

Comment: @Lidaranis I do have full access. Edit: I'm adding a reference to the sdk now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this should be easy.
you split the url into pieces in order to get the parameters.
what is important here is etn=account and id=36345eb0-728c-e611-9421-00153d29152e,
ent is the entity logical name and the id is the id of the record

once you have those you call you set up the organization service connection and you try to get the record

it should look something like this.

```
var entity = crmService.Retrieve("account", Guid.Parse("36345eb0-728c-e611-9421-00153d29152e"),new ColumnSet(true));
```

This should get you the record if it exists.

more details on Retrieve here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrieve.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've managed to get it to the stage it's almost working. Retrieve throws an error if no result is returned but otherwise thanks for the help :). It helped out a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `Retrieve` method is that it throws an exception when there is no record found by given identifier. If you're unsure if the record exists or not it is better to go via `RetrieveMultiple`.

```
// do actual initialization - but that's another topic :)
IOrganizationService organizationService = null;

var query = new QueryExpression
{
  NoLock = true,
  TopCount = 1,
  EntityName = "account",
  // if you want to check just for existence of record use ColumnSet(false)
  // if you want to check entity columns use ColumnSet(true) 
  // or specify columns you want to fetch
  ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(false)
};

query.Criteria.AddCondition(
  "accountid", 
  ConditionOperator.Equal, 
  new Guid("36345eb0-728c-e611-9421-00153d29152e"));

var entities = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(query);

// entities.Entities is guaranteed to be not null
if (entities.Entities.Count == 0)
{
  // snap - no such entity
  return;
}

var entity = entities.Entities[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the URL you have the record id. A better way would be to query the CRM web services and search for that record id in the database.

Comment: Glad i could help